# Many to Many - Prolog / Excel

Tags: excel, prolog, excel-formula

In Prolog I have a db like this:

```
invoice(number,item,product,value).

invoice('2015/01',1,coffee,100).
invoice('2015/02',1,water,50).
invoice('2015/02',2,coffee,100).
invoice('2015/03',1,milk,80).
invoice('2015/03',2,cake,150).
```

I need to ask Prolog this question: How many invoices have NO coffee or water ?
In this case the answer would be 1 (the invoice number 2015/03)

I also wanted to answer this question in an Excel DB. I use a "=countifs" function but it only gives me the number of items that are not coffee or water... something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(D4:D11;"<>"&"coffee";D4:D11;"<>"&"water")
```

it gives me 2 in this example,

But I would like to have only the number of invoices.

Comment: In Prolog, you can use for example `setof/3`: `?- setof(N, I^P^V^(invoice(N,I,P,V), dif(P,water), dif(P,coffee)), Ns), length(Ns, N).`, yielding the invoice numbers `Ns = ['2015/03']` and **N=1**.

Comment: Using all-solution predicates can be used as quick fixes in situations like this one. Do not over-use them, though. Consider moving to different way of data representation.

Comment: I agree with what @repeat has said!

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I'm new in Prolog...I've tried what @mat refer but could get the propoer answer...

Comment: also, what do u mean by "different way of data representation" ? i have this example in an excel table...so i don't know better way to represent it as I did here in Prolog :S

Answer (score -2):

Here is a transcript:

```
$ gprolog
GNU Prolog 1.4.4 (64 bits)
....
Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Daniel Diaz
| ?- ['invoice'].
['invoice'].
yes

| ?-  setof(N, I^P^V^(invoice(N,I,P,V), \+(P = water), \+(P = coffee)), Ns),
      length(Ns, Number).

Ns = ['2015/03']
Number = 1

yes
| ?-
```

To illustrate that the solution is standard, here is a slightly abbreviated transcript using swi-prolog:

```
$ swipl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 6.6.4)
Copyright (c) 1990-2013 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
?- [invoice].
true.

?- setof(N, I^P^V^(invoice(N,I,P,V), \+(P = water), \+(P = coffee)), Ns), length(Ns, Number).
Ns = ['2015/03'],
Number = 1.

?-
```

Comment: I think the cut is a real error here, and you get the 'right' outcome by chance

Comment: @CapelliC. Does `setof/3` above in fact succeed multiple times? (I'm not near a PC, so I can't run the code.) If so, the variables should likely be quantified (like mat did), right?

Comment: @repeat: anonymous variables in setof indicate the OP is misunderstanding the purpose of the builtin. An [interesting answer](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/AuEFJeFT.swinb) has been posted on SWI-Prolog mailing list yesterday

Comment: The cut has been removed. I was mainly focused on providing a full transcript using standard Prolog.

Comment: @CapelliC. Fine. I wonder if we could use term expansion to issue warnings in such cases. And maybe offer some `setof_raw/3` which does no checks. What's your stance on this?

Comment: @repeat: dunno. I think could be difficult, and not much rewarding. By myself, I value more such 'low level' tools like a proper debugger, or syntax highlighting in XPCE, and curated warnings about singletons.... Maybe the point is, Prolog cannot be said to capture the most appealing *computing* logic. There are so many more successful systems...

Comment: @repeat: sorry, maybe I failed to express clearly. It's trivial... for instance, SQL and spreadsheets (M$ Office, let's say) are appealing in their *applicative logic* approach.

Comment: @CapelliC. I get that! In particular spreadsheets impressed me by how far they can take people who are otherwise afraid of coding, but integrate excel into their problem solving toolbox.